# How can I wrap both an image and a text label in an anchor?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu section that a profile png with a sign in next to it. It needs to be an anchor all together, that way when you hover over it it's a link that goes to the log-in page, both the img and text but all together... If I'm making sense to you. I cant figure it out. Below is code so far:

```
<div class="signin-div topbar-section">

        <a class="sign-in" href="#sign-in"><img class="signin-img" src="images/profile-icon.png" alt="profile-icon">Sign in</a>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.sign-in {
        float: left;
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 12px;
        margin-left: -14px;
    }
.signin-img {
        width: 25px;
        margin: 10px 10px;
        float: left;
```

Disclaimer, this code works (centered with the rest of the code for the top-bar-ul and it's not what I want it to be regarding one big anchor) I know it comes up not looking correctly as it should.

Comment: Seems to work. Both the image and Sign-In link are clickable. Are you trying to do something with the positioning? https://jsfiddle.net/t30sd57L/

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Images, text, and many other things are wrapped in anchors all over the internet.

Comment: Maybe you need to post what's *not* working.

Comment: What you have should work, but `href="#sign-in"` wouldn't be redirecting to a url...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're looking for but if you want an image and text to work as a link when you need to have a group/block as the link. (sorry if the way my words put it seams weird/confusing. in that case, I hope my example will do the work)

for example:

```html
<html>
<body>

<div style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; border: 1px solid black;">
  <a href="http://google.com" style="text-align: center;">
    <div>
        <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/o_collection_png/green_dark_grey/256x256/plain/user.png" alt="user Image"> 
        <br> 
        user
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just some friendly tips. Might move that `display: block;` into the actual style declaration since currently it's invalid, but in reality it's not necessary since `div` is a block level element by default. The `div` after the anchor is redundant and unnecessary, and the `<center>` tag isn't html5 valid. Cheers :)

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks, ill make the necessary changes at once!  ^^